# Resolving data in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, snapshot

**Introduction:**

I have a search-box that let's you select a tv show, which then logs the title of the show you clicked, as well as the id for that show. I define this in my:

*landingpage.component*

```
<li (click)="selectShow(list.title)" [routerLink]="['/details', list.id]" 
*ngFor="let list of shows"> {{list.show}} </li>
```

When a *li* is clicked, it sends the `list.id` as a parameter to my */details* component. `selectShow` just logs the name (`list.title`) of the show that was clicked.

**My problem:**

I cannot seem to figure out how to `resolve` my `list.title` value, so that it appears in my */details* route in `this.route.snapshot.data['title']`

**My code:**

*app.routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TitleResolver } from './services/title.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPage },
  {
    path: 'details/:id', component: ResultPage,
    resolve: {
      title: TitleResolver //hopefully contains 'title' data here?
    }
   }
  }
];
```

*resultpage.component.ts*

```
  title; //variable we will assign to title

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  this.route.data
    .subscribe((data: { title: Title}) => {
      console.log(title);
    });
```

*title.service.ts*

```
// this gives us the name of the clicked show
class ShowService {
  fetchTitle(title) {
    return title;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class TitleResolver {
  constructor(private showservice: ShowService) { }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.showservice.fetchTitle(route.params.title);
  }
}
```

**My question**

What are the intermediate step(s) that I need to do in order to send the selected `list.title` value from my *landingpage.component* data to my *app.routing.module.ts*, so that I can receive it in my *resultpage.component* ?

Comment: You are using the `resolve` keyword for data, when you should really be using the keyword `data`. Change `resolve` to `data` in your route declaration, and give that a try.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks! I can now see the string "title" in my result component. However, I still am un-sure how to send the actual title data, instead of the temporary string I have at the moment. (updated the question)

Comment: You cannot pass dynamic data in the route `data` object. Only static, key/value pair data is allowed there; it cannot change throughout the lifetime of the application. You will want to rethink this. Maybe a title lookup based on the route parameter you are passing(?). A title service, so to speak.

Comment: thanks @R.Richards, this is proving to be difficult. Do you happen to have any examples on-hand?

Comment: Here is a good example of how to implement a [Resolver](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-event-view-cli/blob/master/src/app/sessions/shared/session-resolver.service.ts).

Comment: I'd just use a shared service to pass data along. Using routes is mostly about stuff you want to have reflected in the browsers URL bar.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , yeah, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. My router already passes the ID in the url, and all that works great. I just can't get the title value I want